# Rstudio - package installation problems

Tags: r

I have some issue, during package installation in R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) ubuntu machine:

```
install.packages("randomForest")
```

> Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
>        (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>        Warning in install.packages :
>        'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable

How to resolve it?

Comment: Run R with `sudo`. Regular user is not able to write into `/usr/local`